# compare parameter dates with dataset date field in custom code

Tags: date, parameters, compare, ssrs-2012

I need to create a report that displays net working days, excluding holidays. This needs to be a calculation or a calculated field. I have custom code to get the weekends accounted for, and have a Holiday dataset that has all the holidays I need to look for in it.

I have set up a hidden parameter on the report for my Holiday dates. The code below runs, but I get a #Error.  As you can see have tried extracting and comparing the Year, Month and Day separately, as I thought it was maybe a date/time issue. That still produced #Error.

Function NumWorkDays(ByRef startDate As Date,  ByRef endDate As Date) as Integer

```
dim i as integer
dim x as integer
dim totalDays as Integer
dim WeekendDays as Integer
dim HolidayDays as integer
dim sDate as Date
dim numWeekdays as Integer

numWeekdays = 0
WeekendDays = 0
HolidayDays = 0
sDate=startDate

totalDays = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, startDate , endDate ) + 1
```

for i = 1 to totalDays

```
    if DatePart(dateinterval.weekday,sDate ) = 1 then
        WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
    end if
    if DatePart(dateinterval.weekday, sDate ) = 7 then
        WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
    end if
     sDate = DateAdd("d", 1, sDate )
next i
```

sDate=startDate

for x = 1 to totalDays

```
    if DatePart(dateinterval.weekday,sDate ) <> 1 or 
         DatePart(dateinterval.weekday,sDate ) <> 7 then
        for i = 1 to Report.Parameters!HolidayParam.Count()
            if Year(Report.Parameters!HolidayParam.Value(i))=Year(sDate) and
               Month(Report.Parameters!HolidayParam.Value(i))=Month(sDate) and 
                Day(Report.Parameters!HolidayParam.Value(i))= Day(sDate) then           
               HolidayDays = HolidayDays + 1
               Exit For                
            End if
         next i
     end if
    sDate = DateAdd("d", 1, sDate )
```

next x

```
numWeekdays  = totalDays - WeekendDays -HolidayDays
return numWeekdays
```

End Function

Just looking for ideas as to where I have gone wrong!  Thank you!

Comment: I have stepped through the code and it produces the #Error at the If Year(Report.Parameters...etc...And it still produces it if I use "If Report.Parameters!HolidayParam.Value(i)=sDate then"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got this.  Being new to SSRS I had a difficult time not being able to step through the custom code or put in breakpoints to display values as they occurred!  It was simple, it needed to be a multi-valued parameter.  I did not check that as I was keeping it hidden, it didn't strike me that it needed that.
I discovered the problem by putting a text box in a Report Header and simply displaying the count of my parameter. When it showed "1", I knew I had the problem!

The updated code snippet is (all the rest remained the same):

```
for i = 0 to Report.Parameters!HolidayParam.Count()-1
    if Report.Parameters!HolidayParam.Value(i))=sDate then         
        HolidayDays = HolidayDays + 1
        Exit For                
     End if
next i
```